# object[] to List<Interface> returns null

Tags: c#, generics, interface

If I have an object which looks like:

```
class Person : IProxy
{
    // Properties
}
```

And I have a method which returns an `object` which is actually a `List<Person>`:

```
object GetList()
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

    person.Add(new Person());
    person.Add(new Person());

    return people;
}
```

Why does the following code result in null?

```
var obj = GetList() as List<IProxy>;
```

But the code below returns a List:

```
var obj = GetList() as List<Person>;
```

In the Watch panel of Visual Studio, my type is reported as:

```
object {System.Collections.Generic.List<Person>}
```

Comment: A `List<Person>` is _not_ a `List<IProxy>` regardless of Person's relationship to IProxy. There's heaps of questions about this on stackoverflow (contra vs covariance). In short, you can do this: `(GetList() as List<Person>).Cast<IProxy>();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `List<Person>` and `List<IProxy>` are two different types so converting one to another may yield null.

```
GetList().OfType<IProxy>()
```

will do what you want. You can also use

```
GetList().Cast<IProxy>()
```

Personally I prefer OfType because it doesn't throw an exception when the collection contains heterogeneous types

[Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) may answer more of your questions.

Comment: As suggested in the comment to the question, it is better to use Cast<IProxy>() instead of OfType<IProxy>(). In fact, OfType<IProxy>() is filtering out all the elements that are not of type IProxy. In this case the result is the same, but not in general.
Furthermore, if obj needs to be really a list, the right expression is GetList().Cast<IProxy>().ToList()

Comment: The problem with this is that the return of GetList() is an object, not an IEnumerable, and casting to type IProxy results in an invalid casting exception. Again, I can cast to List<Person> but not List<IProxy> to get the enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

Because a `List<People>` is a different type to `List<IProxy>`.  Imagine you had `class Cat : IProxy`.  If you could cast `List<People>` to `List<IProxy>` you could then add a `Cat` to it, which I assume you wouldn't want.  What's missing is generic contravariance here, for example, in java you could legitimately cast your list to `List<? extends IProxy>`, which would allow you to read `IProxy` objects from the list, but not write anything to it.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Actually I do need to add a list of IProxy items which may be of differing types. The code above was an abstraction I made to test the logic (and make the question easier).

Comment: If you need to consolidate multiple instances of `List<T>` where `T` is not the same, but always implements `IProxy`, then you can create a list `proxies = new List<IProxy>();` and call `proxies.AddRange(people); proxies.AddRange(otherProxyTypeList);` etcetera.

Answer (score -2):

Why is the return type of `GetList()` `object`?  It would make more sense to specify `List<Person>` or `IList<Person>`.  That way, you wouldn't have to cast after calling the method.

If you want a `List<IProxy>` from your method, you would do this:

```
List<IProxy> GetList() 
{ 
    List<IProxy> people = new List<IProxy>(); 

    people.Add(new Person()); 
    people.Add(new Person()); 

    return people; 
}
```

then

```
var obj = GetList();
```

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This is true, but I am using reflection to return all properties on an object at runtime, and the value is returned as an object, not a strongly typed List.

Comment: @JD that was not apparent from the code sample you posted, which shows a method that creates a list and returns it as an object.

Comment: Absolutely, but the question I asked was specific to the problem, which was that a List<Person> is not a List<IProxy> - in my comment on your answer I was giving you context as to a reason why your proposed method might not always be the appropriate way. Not a downvoter btw, no hard feelings.